# how to update table(new_DB) from old table(old_DB)

Tags: sql-server

What I have:
1 table(table is in both DB's)
2 databases(currently used + archived from last year(old))
"ID" is the primary key for the table.

my issue:
archived database table has rows in it that is not present in the currently used database table. Can anyone tell me how I go about updating the currently used database table from the old database table(i.e. insert * unique rows from old database table into new database table)

It sounds simple enough but wanted some advice before proceeding as I DO NOT want duplicate rows, I just want to throw the rows in the old table(that IS NOT present in the currently used database table) into the new one(copy only is fine).

I hope I explained clearly enough.

Comment: If a row can be uniquely identified by it's primary/unique keys this sounds as a perfect use of MySQL's `REPLACE` statement (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html). It would insert the missing rows and update the rows already present

Comment: edwardmp ~ I have thought about using replace, but dont really need to update existing rows, just need to throw the rows from the old table into the new database table that isnt present, was hoping there is another eeasier way to go about it

Comment: Are you using MySQL? REPLACE isn't ANSI SQL, so you can get different answers if you specify dbms...

Comment: The DBMS I am using is Sql Server Management Studio(Sql Server 2008)(SORRY SHOULD HAVE PUT THIS IN MY ORIGINAL POST)

Comment: Nitpicking: "Sql Server Management Studio" is not a DBMS, it's SQL client used (exclusively) for SQL Server.

Comment: I like your nitpicking:P I must apologize for my ignorance lol its rdms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can usually address tables from other databases by prefixing the database name: `new_db.foo_table` or `old_db.foo_table`. This way you can look for rows in the old table that have no duplicates in the new table:

```
select * 
from old_db.foo_table as old_foo
where not exists (
   select 1
   from new_db.foo_table as new_foo
   where new_foo.key_field = old_foo.key_field 
         -- add more comparisons as needed
);
```

Then you can use the `insert into new_db.foo_table select ...` syntax to put the records into the new table.

Answer (score 2):

Insert rows from the new table only if row with same id not exists in old table:

```
insert into old_table select * from new_table nt
                      where not exists (select 1 from old_table
                                        where id = nt.id)
```

(Specifying columns, both inserted and selected, is nice - but I'm lazy here...)

Answer (score 1):

Use LEFT JOIN filtering NULLs in target table. I think it will be faster

```
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE
SELECT ot.* FROM OLD_TABLE ot
LEFT JOIN NEW_TABLE nt on ot.ID = nt.ID
WHERE nt.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: Wow I just wanna thank everyone who commented on the quick responses. Unfortunately I cannot test which query would be faster(cant go full geek right now)

Comment: SOOOO after trying out both queries, I think someting unnattended is going on, here are my results:
newdb_table_row_count:6,272 
olddb_table_row_count: 12,595
So my query result set should show a row count of 5873
but I am getting 7622..
Im not really understanding as to why this is, as the ID column is the primary key... Can someone elaborate?